# Error in <limits> compiling an old code using VSC2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an old code, but using Visual Studio Community 2017 had no problem to compile it. Yesterday, I updated to Visual Studio Community 2019 and I opened the old .vxproj file, but I got tens of errors like this while compiling include file limits:

limits(900,39): error C3615: constexpr function 'std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN' cannot result in a constant expression

limits(901,30): message : failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'

I guess the problem may be with the old .vxproj file, but I have no idea how can I fix it without creating a new project form scatch. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a guess, perhaps you have some custom INCLUDE paths that point to old versions of the headers? Perhaps review these settings?

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. It tries to compile the correct file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\limits(900,39):"

Comment: You should also check the build tools and C++ standard used in the project. Looks like the compiler doesn't recognize `constexpr` somehow.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you can certainly do so, but please do it by posting an answer. (And please don't add "solved" to the title.)

Comment: OK. I will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. There was a few preprocessor directives which caused the problem. After removig them I was able to compile:

```
__builtin_huge_val()=HUGE_VAL
__builtin_huge_valf()=HUGE_VALF
__builtin_nan=nan
__builtin_nanf=nanf
__builtin_nans=nan
__builtin_nansf=nanf
__is_assignable=__is_trivially_assignable
```

Once I have tried the Intel compiler in Visual Studio, it required these settings, but it seems I forgot to remove them.

I have decided not to delete this post, but answer my own question. It may be useful for someone with a similar problem, or if you want to make fun of your colleague :-) It took me a very long time to find out what the problem was.